# Displaying model to non razor dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

Is it possible to display a model for an ordinary html dropdown in cshtml
or should i use ajax for that alone? what is the best option?

```html
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>            
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationId)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationStartDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationEndDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationAdult)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationChildren)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationRoomDesc)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationRoomType)</td>
                    <td><select id="hotelroom" name="cs3" class="cs3 form-control input-small"></select></td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReservationRoomStatus)</td>      
                    <td><input type="button" id="editTable"></td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dropdown list like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    modelItem => modelItem.AvailableHotelRoomOptions, 
    new SelectList(Model.AvailableHotelRoomOptions.Select(@r => @r.OptionName)),
    new { @id = "hotelroom", @class = "cs3 form-control input-small" }
)
```

Or like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    modelItem => modelItem.AvailableHotelRoomOptions, 
    new SelectList(Model.AvailableHotelRoomOptions, "OptionId", "OptionValue"),
    new { @id = "hotelroom", @class = "cs3 form-control input-small" }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Razor to render the `<option>` tags like any other tag.

I assume you have an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableHotelRoomOptions` with the potential options in your model.

```
<td>
    <select id="hotelroom" name="cs3" class="cs3 form-control input-small"> 
    @foreach(var selectListItem in Model.AvailableHotelRoomOptions) {
        @{ string selectedAttr = selectListItem.Selected ? "selected = \"selected\"" : string.Empty; }
        <option value="@selectListItem.Value" @selectedAttr>
            @selectListItem.Text
        </option>
    }
    </select>
</td>
```

PS: make sure the Id and Name attributes of the `<select>` match the naming convention expected by the MVC ModelBinder so it can be bound back!